# Implementing a floating dropdown panel for android toolbar

Tags: android, material-design

Iam working on an tablet app that needs a dropdown panel that flots on top of everything inclunding my toolbar. And should look something like

[image]

Can you please suggest the best UI widget that best suits this purpose, putting into consideration elevation and alignment inside the toolbar

Answer (score 0):

For me it's a PopupWindow shown with [showAsDropDown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAsDropDown(android.view.View)). You would have to prepare a layout with highlit back button and the product list. Then create a PopupWindow with that layout set as a content.

The other option is to prepare the popup as a custom, hidden layout lying on your main screen (use FrameLayout) and change its visibility when needed.

I'm not sure, but you may need a custom ViewOutlineProvider with [convex path outline](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Outline.html#setConvexPath(android.graphics.Path)). PopupWindow may be unable to drop a non-rectangular shadow like on your screenshot. In such case you would have to set its background to transparent (or maybe null?), disable window's shadow and cast shadow with custom ViewOutlineProvider.